# how to compare data between 2 databases

Tags: sql, checksum

i have a table in my database that is updated from a table in another database. I want to compare the data in 2 tables and if some data don't exist in my database then istranferred column in source database convert to zero. how can I do that using checksum and update?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data and also the expected result. (All as formatted text, no images.) [mcve]

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

I have a table in my source database like that:

questionid  objid   sbjid   editedstatus    Istransferred
1   20  21  0   0
2   20  22  1   1
3   22  22  1   1

And automatically the records that have editedstatus=1 are transferred to my destination database. I want to check the numbers of data in two database  and somehow if any data has been deleted in destination database, the  value of istransferred colmn of the deleted  row converts to zero in source database.